# The number of regex find operations in progress has reached its limit. (Code: 154, Version: 1.2.20)

Tags: ios, regex, xcode, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm using Parse for database. Now when i query to Parse, there is an error:

`Error: The number of regex find operations in progress has reached its limit. (Code: 154, Version: 1.2.20)`

The query codes are

```
    PFQuery* query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Place"];
    [query setLimit:MAX_ROW_PFQUERY];
    [query orderByAscending:@"updatedAt"];
    [query whereKey:@"city" containsString:city];
    [query whereKey:@"country" containsString:country];
    [query whereKey:@"updatedAt" greaterThanOrEqualTo:date];
```

Anyone knows the problems? Please help me fix that :(

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

old question but thought i would tell you my findings because i have hit the same road block. the problem is that parse apparently limit the amount of calls per application (on each users device) can call to 160 api calls per minute

https://www.parse.com/questions/code154-errorthe-number-of-regex-find-operations-in-progress-has-reached-its-limit